# Mysql query to search posts and comments, return total comment count

Tags: mysql, sql

Am trying to write a query that

1. Searches tables Posts and Comments for a string
2. Returns matching Posts along with their total comment count if there is a match on either table.

I have:

```
SELECT Posts.id, Comments.id, Count(DISTINCT Comments.id)
FROM Posts 
LEFT JOIN Comments ON Comments.postid = Posts.id 
WHERE ( Posts.text LIKE '%test%' 
          OR ( Comments.text LIKE '%test%'  
          AND Comments.deleted = false ) ) 
       AND Posts.approved = true 
       AND Posts.deleted = false 
GROUP BY Posts.id
```

The problem with this query is that the where is filtering my Comments.id count, so instead of returning the total number of comments in the post, it returns the number of comments matching 'test'.
How can I achieve what I want in a single query?

Comment: Please describe the logic.  There is more to your query than what you describe.

Comment: Post a sample data with the current output you're getting and your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `GROUP BY` clause is not needed:

```
SELECT Posts.id, 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Comments c 
      WHERE c.postid = Posts.id AND c.deleted = false
    ) AS total_post_comments
FROM Posts 
WHERE Posts.approved = true 
    AND Posts.deleted = false 
    AND (
        Posts.text LIKE '%test%'
        OR EXISTS(
            SELECT 1 FROM Comments
            WHERE Comments.text LIKE '%test%'
              AND Comments.deleted = false
              AND Comments.postid = Posts.id
        )
    )
```

Comment: This works! Am curious if there is there a way to do this without subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all posts where the post or a comment contains the string of interest.  For the ones that match, you want the total comment count.

For this, using `having`:

```
SELECT p.id, Count(c.id)
FROM Posts p JOIN
     Comments c
     ON c.postid = p.id 
GROUP BY p.id
WHERE p.approved = true AND
      p.deleted = false 
HAVING p.text LIKE '%test%' OR
       SUM( c.text LIKE '%test%' AND c.deleted = false ) > 0;
```

Comment: This does not work. No Join? No And between Where conditions?

Comment: Was not able to get this to work, you understood my question correctly.

Comment: @david987 . . . What issue are you encountering?